# SQL Server Issue with Update while using TVP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following sql

```
DECLARE @tmpSelectedData   TABLE  -- table variable
        (SlNo  INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
         ,dataID INT NULL
         ,ValID INT NULL
         ,DdrID INT NULL
         ,InrID INT NULL
         ,IprID INT NULL)

-- inserting into table variable
INSERT INTO @tmpSelectedData(dataID)  
    SELECT 
        SQ.dataID    
    FROM 
        @SelectedQuestions SQ 

    -- Update the table variable with some values

    tblData
       dataID,ValID,DdrID,InrID,IprID 
        1-    2-  3  - 4-   5
        2-    7-  4  - 5-       8
        3-    8-  2  - 4-       3
        4-    0-  1  - 2-       5

    @SelectedData  
        dataID
         2
         3
         4

    @tmpSelectedData    
        dataID,ValID,DdrID,InrID,IprID 
            2-    
            3-    
        4-    

UPDATE @tmpSelectedData   
SET IprID = D.dataID,
    DdrID = D.DdrID,
    InrID = D.InrID 
FROM tblData D 
INNER JOIN @SelectedData SD ON SD.dataID = D.dataID
```

Using this query, all the rows of `@tmpSelectedData` will be updated with the value which is corresponding to the first row of `tblData`

Expected result in `@tmpSelectedData`:

```
   dataID,ValID,DdrID,InrID,IprID 
        2-    7-  4  - 5-       8
        3-    8-  2  - 4-       3
        4-    0-  1  - 2-       5
```

Actual result in `@tmpSelectedData`:

```
   dataID,ValID,DdrID,InrID,IprID 
        2-    7-  4  - 5-       8
        3-    7-  4  - 5-       8
        4-    7-  4  - 5-       8
```

it will update only with the first value

```
UPDATE @tmpSelectedData   
SET dataID = D.dataID,
    DdrID = D.DdrID,
    InrID = D.InrID 
FROM tblData D 
INNER JOIN @tmpSelectedData SD ON SD.IprID = D.IprID
```

When I changed it to `@tmpSelectedData` from `@SelectedData` (second query), it will works and update as the expected result.

What is the difference between two queries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the issues with the `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax - if it, in effect, attempts to update the *same* row multiple times, the end result will be *one* of those updates, but which one is indeterminate - **and it doesn't give an error or warning message when this happens**.

What you have in your first `UPDATE` query is a `FROM` clause that doesn't reference the table to be updated at all - it's effectively an uncorrelated query, such that the entire resultset generated by the `FROM` clause applies to all rows in the target table. One row (in this case, the "first", although that is ill defined) has been the row to "win" the update (it should be noted, equally, that there's no guarantee that the same row will "win" against each row in the table being updated).

In your second query, because the table to be updated *is* referenced in the [`FROM` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx):

> Specifies that a table, view, or derived table source is used to provide the criteria for the update operation. For more information, see [`FROM` (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx).
>
> If the object being updated is the same as the object in the `FROM` clause and there is only one reference to the object in the `FROM` clause, an object alias may or may not be specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE @tmpSelectedData   
   SET dataID = D.dataID,
       DdrID = D.DdrID,
       InrID = D.InrID
  FROM tblData D 
 INNER JOIN @tmpSelectedData SD ON SD.IprID = D.IprID 
 WHERE SD.IprID In (SELECT IprID FROM @SelectedData)
```

Try this way.. in your query relationship between @tmpSelectedData and @SelectedData is missing.